# Fuzzy logic and Artificial Intelligence

Tags: terminology, artificial-intelligence, fuzzy

Is it correct to classify fuzzy logic under Artificial Intelligence i.e. can fuzzy logic be considered a concept under the purview of of AI. If not how can we classify fuzzy logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fuzzy logic can be considered a concept under the purview of of AI. Keep in mind that AI is a quite subjective term. E.g., see [AI effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AI_effect).

Comment: Thanks for clarification. It makes sense AI even granting the fact that AI is used very liberally these days.